# Visual Studio 2013. Program cannot find an entry for __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length method in libstdc++-6.dll when starting from .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I am doing a program in C++ in Visual Studio 2013 IDE. The program uses Qt5 and openGL in Qt5.

Everything works when I am building and starting program in IDE (both Debug and Release modes).
But when I am trying to run the program by double clicking the generated .exe file, the following error occurs:

```
Cannot find the entry point for the procedure 
    __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length in library libstdc++-6.dll
```

Do you have any clues what I may doing wrong?